# Replacing a XmlSerializer for a BinarySerializer. What should I know?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I've been using an `XmlSerializer` all this time to serialize my `Project` class to a file. It contains all sorts of information in it. Most stuff is done automatically by the `XmlSerializer`, except for one or two classes that implement `IXmlSerializable`. Now I want to switch to a binary serializer **only** to make the files smaller. I still don't want to serialize private fields or anything like that. I just want it to behave exactly as an XmlSerializer but to generate smaller files.

Is there any easy way to do this, or will I have to make lots of changes to my application? Or, is there any other kind of serializer I should be using instead?

Comment: " I still don't want to serialize private fields " - yet that is exactly what `BinaryFormatter` does by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to `BinaryFormatter` is a bad idea here, IMO - it radically changes the behaviour and ***in particular*** your ability to trust the files between versions and between platforms. It also means you are now serializing ***your fields***, which may not be a 1:1 map to the data you *wanted* to serialize (the public members, by default).

If you want *smaller*, perhaps just run it through `DeflateStream` or `GZipStream`. If that isn't enough, my next move would be to switch to something like [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/), for the reason that it behaves **very similarly** (not identically) to `XmlSerializer`, but as a binary serializer (not a field serializer). However, it does *not* respect `IXmlSerializable` - depending on the complexity, that may be easy to side-step.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the easiest solution to make your files smaller is to go the way the current Office XML formats (ODF and the one from MS) go: Zip it. This way, you don't have to change anything in your classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it only for space, might compressing the XML files after serialization be an alternative? This way you would keep readability and you could name your files `project.xml.zip`.